# If $\alpha \vdash \phi$ and $\beta \vdash \phi$, does it mean that $\alpha \cap \beta \vdash \phi$?

Tags: propositional-calculus

I would like to know if this is correct.

Comment: You have to specify that $\alpha, \beta$ are *sets* of formulas.

Comment: But the answer is : NO.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Could I know why it is not correct? For example, if $\alpha$ is included in a set, and $\beta$ included in the same set, then the intersection is also included.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following example :

$A = \{ p \land q \}$ and $B = \{ q \land r \}$.

We have $A \vdash q$ and $B \vdash q$.

But $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and :

> $\emptyset \nvdash q$,

because $q$ is not a *tautology*.

Comment: But, isn't the $\emptyset$ included in all sets, which means $\emptyset \vdash $ any possible set?

Comment: @IliassA No, check the meaning of $\vdash$

Comment: @IliassA - Yes, $\emptyset$ is included in evry set but this does not mean that every set will prove every formula.

Comment: Clear to me now, thanks.